# how to search for strings with []

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

Within [kibana](https://www.elastic.co/products/kibana), how to search for all the `MESSAGES` containing the string `[]`?

If I search using `"hostname []"` it matches the full `MESSAGE` payload as the images below, but how to match all the records containing an empty `[]` ignoring fields like `hostname [3]` but including entries like `foo bar hostname []`?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Standard tokenizer will split the words whenever it encounters a whitespace or a punctuation, excluding special characters, you can see how elasticsearch analyzes:

```
GET _analyze
{
  "analyzer" : "standard",
  "text" : "function []"
}

{
  "tokens": [
    {
      "token": "function",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 8,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 0
    }
  ]
}
```

Is excluding `[]`, now lets test with the `whitespace` analyzer

```
GET _analyze
{
  "analyzer" : "whitespace",
  "text" : "function []"
}
{
  "tokens": [
    {
      "token": "function",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 8,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 0
    },
    {
      "token": "[]",
      "start_offset": 9,
      "end_offset": 11,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 1
    }
  ]
}
```

so for this particular scenario just make a change in the mapping, set in the field the `whitespace` analyzer:

```
 "MESSAGE": {
    "type": "text",
    "analyzer" : "whitespace"
 }
```

[image]